# Direct Linear Transformation in C++ from Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision, svd

I'm not experienced with Python, but I wanted to use this Python function that performs direct linear transformation that I got from this blog post:

https://temugeb.github.io/opencv/python/2021/02/02/stereo-camera-calibration-and-triangulation.html

I've attempted to convert this function into C++. Below is the original Python function as well as my C++ version. Is my C++ version correct? P1 and P2 are 3x4 matrices, and point1 and point2 are two-dimensional vectors.

The issue is that I'm not getting the results I expect, and I don't know if it's because I'm not properly reproducing this DLT function, or if it's something else.

```
def DLT(P1, P2, point1, point2):

    A = [point1[1]*P1[2,:] - P1[1,:],
         P1[0,:] - point1[0]*P1[2,:],
         point2[1]*P2[2,:] - P2[1,:],
         P2[0,:] - point2[0]*P2[2,:]
        ]
    A = np.array(A).reshape((4,4))
    #print('A: ')
    #print(A)

    B = A.transpose() @ A
    from scipy import linalg
    U, s, Vh = linalg.svd(B, full_matrices = False)

    print('Triangulated point: ')
    print(Vh[3,0:3]/Vh[3,3])
    return Vh[3,0:3]/Vh[3,3]
```

And here is my C++ version that I'm hoping is correct:

```
// Perform direct linear transformation
cv::Point3f DLT(cv::Mat P1, cv::Mat P2, cv::Point2f point1, cv::Point2f point2)
{
    // The 3D point to return
    cv::Point3f Retv(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Build the DLT A 4x4 matrix
    cv::Mat A(4, 4, CV_64F);

    // First row
    A.at<double>(0, 0) = ((point1.y * P1.at<double>(2, 0)) - P1.at<double>(1, 0));
    A.at<double>(0, 1) = ((point1.y * P1.at<double>(2, 1)) - P1.at<double>(1, 1));
    A.at<double>(0, 2) = ((point1.y * P1.at<double>(2, 2)) - P1.at<double>(1, 2));
    A.at<double>(0, 3) = ((point1.y * P1.at<double>(2, 3)) - P1.at<double>(1, 3));

    // Second row
    A.at<double>(1, 0) = (P1.at<double>(0, 0) - (point1.x * P1.at<double>(2, 0)));
    A.at<double>(1, 1) = (P1.at<double>(0, 1) - (point1.x * P1.at<double>(2, 1)));
    A.at<double>(1, 2) = (P1.at<double>(0, 2) - (point1.x * P1.at<double>(2, 2)));
    A.at<double>(1, 3) = (P1.at<double>(0, 3) - (point1.x * P1.at<double>(2, 3)));

    // Third row
    A.at<double>(2, 0) = ((point2.y * P2.at<double>(2, 0)) - P2.at<double>(1, 0));
    A.at<double>(2, 1) = ((point2.y * P2.at<double>(2, 1)) - P2.at<double>(1, 1));
    A.at<double>(2, 2) = ((point2.y * P2.at<double>(2, 2)) - P2.at<double>(1, 2));
    A.at<double>(2, 3) = ((point2.y * P2.at<double>(2, 3)) - P2.at<double>(1, 3));

    // Fourth row
    A.at<double>(3, 0) = (P2.at<double>(0, 0) - (point2.x * P2.at<double>(2, 0)));
    A.at<double>(3, 1) = (P2.at<double>(0, 1) - (point2.x * P2.at<double>(2, 1)));
    A.at<double>(3, 2) = (P2.at<double>(0, 2) - (point2.x * P2.at<double>(2, 2)));
    A.at<double>(3, 3) = (P2.at<double>(0, 3) - (point2.x * P2.at<double>(2, 3)));

    // Calculate A transpose
    cv::Mat ATranspose;
    cv::transpose(A, ATranspose);

    // Compute the final matrix on which to perform singular value decomposition
    cv::Mat B = ATranspose * A;

    // Compute singular value decomposition
    cv::Mat w, u, vt;
    cv::SVD::compute(B, w, u, vt);

    // If the result is of the expected size
    if ((4 == vt.rows) && (4 == vt.cols))
    {
        // Get the fourth in homogeneous coordinates
        const double dDivisor = vt.at<double>(3, 3);

        // If we have a non-zero fourth in the homogeneous coordinates
        if (dDivisor != 0.0)
        {
            // Fill in the point to return
            Retv.x = static_cast<float>(vt.at<double>(3, 0) / dDivisor);
            Retv.y = static_cast<float>(vt.at<double>(3, 1) / dDivisor);
            Retv.z = static_cast<float>(vt.at<double>(3, 2) / dDivisor);
        }
    }

    // Return the point we just calculated
    return Retv;
}
```

Comment: That looks approximately correct.  How far off?  Wildly off, or just a shade off?

Comment: @TimRoberts They're wildly off. Originally I was doing it this way as I explained in my previous SO question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76956101/how-to-find-the-world-location-of-a-feature-with-opencv-stereo-camera-triangulat/76969920#76969920

But I decided to try to follow the blog post and do DLT instead. The original way gave me results that were several mm off, which I'm not happy with, but this way gives me complete junk.

Comment: Were you able to try that exact Python code?  Does it produce reasonable results?

Comment: I just read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linear_transformation and think the link would be useful here

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks, I did go ahead and just follow the example and I've verified that my DLT translation is correct (by comparing to the results of cv::triangulatePoints()). I'll go ahead and post the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By translating the entire example in the OP link into C++ and comparing the answer from my DLT with the answer from cv::triangulatePoints(), I've verified that my original translation is correct.